# jquery .post not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working with the following code:

action.php

```
<?php
$_SESSION['passtext'] = $_POST['passtext'];
?>
```

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#clickable").click(function() {
        $.post("action.php", { passtext: "Hello" } );
        alert('refresh the page to see the session text');
    });
});
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="clickable">click me to set session text</a>

<?php if(isset($_SESSION['passtext'])) echo $_SESSION['passtext']; ?>
```

When I click the link, I get the alert, but it seems that action.php isn't running at all -- because I will refresh the page and I see no echo of $_SESSION['passtext'] (it isn't being set)

There are no errors in the Error Console either

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this line at the beginning of your files before you deal with sessions:

```
session_start();
```

From the PHP docs:

> session_start() creates a session or
>   resumes the current one based on a
>   session identifier passed via a GET or
>   POST request, or passed via a cookie.

Comment: oh man i cant believe i forgot that, this was actually a huge post sequence i paired down to ask this simple question - turns out i was missing the session_start, now i feel like a dummy

Answer (score 1):

Try using JQuery AJAX Instead:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "action.php",
   data: "passtext=Hello"
});
```

Comment: You "stated the obvious" and solved a problem for me! I was passing non-assoc data (eg. data: "Hello Bob") and nothing was happening. Noting your suggestion, I changed it to "data: "Hello=Bob" and everything worked! So, it turns out that only associative values can be passed. Go figger. (Yes, I know I should have known that already... grrr).